# HEROKU: Permission denied (publickey) fatal:could not read from remote respository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have been searching for the past few days for a way to fix this. I am able to log into heroku fine, see my keys and apps, but when I try to Heroku push origin master I keep getting this error. I can generate a key, remove them add them again, totally lost

```
C:\Users\petey_000\rails_projects\sample_app>heroku keys
=== peteywiggin@gmail.com Keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...1Xr/y7nw== petey_000@PETES-PC
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...UCb8Glpsxt petey_000@PETES-PC


C:\Users\petey_000\rails_projects\sample_app>ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

C:\Users\petey_000\rails_projects\sample_app>ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-FQ9fnRDJkhj7/agent.4812; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=840; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 840;

C:\Users\petey_000\rails_projects\sample_app>ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

C:\Users\petey_000\rails_projects\sample_app>eval `ssh-agent`
FILE DOES NOT EXIST.
```

Comment: try to do `heroku login`

Comment: The Heroku Login worked fine, when I put eval "$(ssh-agent)" it just said "file does not exist"